# Can't list folder on USB connected drive but it's there!

Tags: ls, mtp

When I run

```
ls /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=OPPO_SM6375-QRD__SN%3AD5F9F680_d5f9f680/
```

The following is returned

```
'Internal shared storage' 'SD card'
```

When I run

```
ls /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=OPPO_SM6375-QRD__SN%3AD5F9F680_d5f9f680/SD\ card/
ls /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=OPPO_SM6375-QRD__SN%3AD5F9F680_d5f9f680/Internal\ shared\ storage/
```

I get the message **"No such file or directory"**.

I used to hit TAB to complete the path but it stops after

```
ls /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=OPPO_SM6375-QRD__SN%3AD5F9F680_d5f9f680/
```

If I run

```
ls /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=OPPO_SM6375-QRD__SN%3AD5F9F680_d5f9f680/*
```

the following is returned:

```
'/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=OPPO_SM6375-QRD__SN%3AD5F9F680_d5f9f680/Internal shared storage':
Alarms  Audiobooks  Documents   Movies  Notifications   Pictures  Recordings  temp
Android  DCIM       Download    Music   oua_classifier  Podcasts  Ringtones

'/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=OPPO_SM6375-QRD__SN%3AD5F9F680_d5f9f680/SD card':
Alarms  Audiobooks  DCIM    Download  Music     Pictures  Recordings
Android  data       Documents   Movies   Notifications  Podcasts  Ringtones
```

So the two directories (`Internal shared drive` and `SD card`) are not empty.

This used to work until a few days ago. There have been Linux Mint updates but no phone update. I have a second phone with two similar directories and everything works on that phone when connected.

In the file explorer, nemo, I can navigate the directories. However, there is an oddity, which didn't exist when all was working. If I press the toolbar button *Toggle Location Entry*, the following appears.

For 'Internal shared storage':

```
mtp://OPPO_SM6375-QRD__SN%3AD5F9F680_d5f9f680/%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8EInternal%20shared%20storage%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E
```

For 'SD card':

```
mtp://OPPO_SM6375-QRD__SN%3AD5F9F680_d5f9f680/%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8ESD%20card%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8E%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E
```

When I saw the above, I tried putting the path in quotes:

```
ls "/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=OPPO_SM6375-QRD__SN%3AD5F9F680_d5f9f680/"
```

Then when I hit TAB after final forward slash, the two long folder names above (with all the %E%80, etc) were shown and the directories were listed!

This is made worse because I have a Python script that takes the full paths to the two directories as input (`Internal shared storage` and `SD card`) but now when trying to recurse them, the script fails. It doesn't see the directories. Again, this used to be fine.

Please can someone shed light on this and tell me what I've done to get into this state!

`inxi` output:

```
CPU: dual core Intel Core i7-6500U (-MT MCP-) speed/min/max: 700/400/3100 MHz
Kernel: 6.2.6-060206-generic x86_64 Up: 20h 34m
Mem: 7048.4/15765.9 MiB (44.7%) Storage: 1.38 TiB (48.5% used) Procs: 347
Shell: Zsh inxi: 3.3.13
```

I tried updating the kernel (as seen above) to 6.x instead of the default 5.x for Linux Mint but both exhibit the same behaviour.

I also updated `zsh` to the latest version, 5.9.

Comment: Is there an online Linux Mint changelog were you could track the change that caused this?

Comment: The update manager lists the packages that have changed. In the past week, there have been at least 60 packages that have changed! I looked through them to see if there was anything that seemed relevant, such as file system related. The kernel was one change and I've reverted that (and gone forward too). I have the option of using Timeshift to go back two weeks but I'm travelling so if anything goes wrong, I may find it difficult to recover until I get home.

Comment: does it show in the output of `mount` or `df`?

Comment: The drives don't appear in `mount` or `df`. Same for the phone that is working. Are you thinking I could mount the drives manually? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: By an incredible coincidence, the phone today said an update was available: to upgrade from Android 12 to 13. I upgraded and that fixed the problem! It's a mystery why it was working under Android 12 then stopped working.